# Customising Mule Shutdown- Stop listening to JMS queue

Tags: jms, mule, mule-component

Is it possible to customize shutting down of mule such that it stops the jms inbound first than other services. The problem is when the mule is shutting down it pickups the message from jms queue for processing which fails in later stages because the other services have been shut down by mule. The mule shuts down the services/connectors in random order. Is there a way to customise mule to stop listening to inbound queue then stop other services ?

Answer (score 1):

I would try with a shutdown [context notification](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Mule+Server+Notifications), if you do a blocking one stopping your inbound endpoints and assuming your don't reenter in your flow, you should get your behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking of another way to stop inbound connectors , and then restarting them back , once the outbound services are up. You can get the handle to the connectors through the contexts. All code goes in exception handling.